# Can't initialize variable without setting to final

Tags: android, global-variables

So this has been driving me a little crazy. All I am trying to do is set a variable to a character

```
String optr = "+";

    Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            optr = "+";  // Here I am trying to initilize and I get errors
        }
    });
```

but I am getting errors such as

```
Cannot refer to a non-final variable optr inside an inner class defined in a different method
```

When I do set the variable to final, I get another error

```
The final local variable optr cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type
```

So I am really unsure on what to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be final bcoz you are using it inside a inner class.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#accessing

> An anonymous class cannot access local variables in its enclosing
>   scope that are not declared as final or effectively final.

You can declare it as a instance variable or you need to make it `final`. If you make it final it is k but you are re-assigning it again in the inner class and hence you got

```
The final local variable optr cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.3

So Declare it before `onCreate` inside `Activity` class like `String optr`.

Answer (score 1):

> you are getting this error because optr is declared as local variable not instance
>
> Cannot refer to a non-final variable optr inside an inner class defined in a different method
>
> Again when you declare the local variable as final you can access the variable from anonymous class but though it is final so you can not change the value of optr